# Font corruption on a netbook

Tags: display, fonts, troubleshooting

Lately I'm getting really weird font issues. I'm not sure what to make of it. Here's a [picture](http://img15.imageshack.us/i/screenshotuw.png/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities that come to mind, after seeing your picture.

Video card driver may have been updated and creating the problem, ie not refreshing properly. Minimize then Maximize any application window, if font gets corrected then it is the video card driver.

or

It could be the video card is overheating. Use those compressed air cans to clean the vents of the netbook/laptop. Make sure your netbook has good ventilation and that the vents are not obstructed.